# jquery remember state of animation after page reload

Tags: jquery, location, jquery-animate, reload

I have a block following my menu buttons, to indicate which one is active. Is there a way to keep the block's location after a refresh?
As of now the location gets reseted when I press a link in a subpage.

jquery code:

```
$( "button",document.body ).click(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var offsetBody = $("body").offset();
  $( "#block" )
     .animate({
    left: (offset.left - offsetBody.left) 
  }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery is a client-side script. When you reload a page or navigate to a new page you request the information from the server, meaning that all client-side data is lost.

There would however, depending on you precise problem, be a number of solutions.

1. If you are only interested in the location of the block on each page individually then you could code some element in the mark-up to have an attribute value equal to something, check this value upon loading if the DOM and move the block accordingly.
2. You could use client-side cookies to store a value and upon loading of the DOM check this variable and animate the block accordingly.
3. You could use an AJAX call to set a server-side variable in PHP and use this variable to dynamically create the element in 1.

Would any of these three solutions work do you think? I can go in to more detail if you can tell me more precisely how you would like to accomplish this.

For method 1.

Use the JQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method such that;

Markup

```
<meta name="description" content="home" />
```

JQuery

```
var page = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
if (page == "home") {
    // you know where it should be
} else if (page == "account") {
    // you know where it should be
}
```

However I'm a little concerned this isn't exactly the functionality you want, is it?

For method 3

Markup

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $pos = $_SESSION['position'];
    echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $pos . '" />'
?>
```

JQuery

```
var position;
// perform animation stuff and store position in the variable
// make a post() request after the position has changed
$.post("position.php", { pos: position } );
```

PHP position.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['position'] = $_POST['pos'];
?>
```

Comment: Solution 1 seems to fit me, i dont wanna depend on cookies since it is often blocked on workplaces. If you could just give me some code example then I should be able to modify it for my site. im very grateful

Comment: Im not sure if your solution will get me there in the end. I made it work with iframe, but I rather not use iframe since it will give me alot of other problems. Look here [link](http://vindfrisk.se/test2/) to see what im looking for.

Comment: Could you please then try to define exactly the functionality you desire, the simplest model possible I am not sure I completely get what you are aiming for. Your link shows a page that seems broken?! My bad it is your test page I get it.

Comment: Well I looked at your page you are changing things client side that need to be saved on the server therefore you need to either perform an AJAX request (which would go nicely with what you have) that interacts with a PHP script or save the variable in a cookie. You rule out cookies so you can either go with the HTML5 option Gran states or try an AJAX request, AJAX is actually very easy.

Comment: Really, thanks for the effort and time you put in Neilos. I don't know how to do it with AJAX, but I will use my best friend Google to try to find some snippets I can analyze.

Comment: Awesome, gonna give a chance after I've slept. 05:34 in the morning now ;)

Comment: @Vindfrisk remember to vote for Neilos. Really good answer. ;)

Comment: Don't worry about that, have you got it working yet? do you need any further help?

Comment: I ended up not using it at all, but I learnt a lot! I very much appriciate your help. I have a new problem, now with css... take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857008/css-firefox-expands-parent-div-but-not-ie-or-chrome-bug :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the position in the following object.
 1. Local storage(browser support)
   In the modern browsers, you can store the position in Localstorage.
   pros:fast, user friendly.
   cons:you need to handle the cross browser.
 2. Server side.
   Otherwise, you need to store it in the serverside()
   pros:No need to take browsers into account.
   cons:Slow, you need to concern internet latency.
 3. Cookies.

Comment: local storage is HTML 5 and whilst this is in it's infancy you are striking off a whole heap of potential visitors.

Comment: Right, that's why I said the modern browsers, each solution has its pros and cons, right? If you can tolerate the cons, then you can benefit from the pros.

Comment: I'm not disputing that fact I'm just being objective =)