# CSS Firefox expands parent div but not IE or Chrome, bug?

Tags: css, browser

I'm trying to do a blog stylish design with a "date block" to the left of parenting div. It works in IE and Chrome but in Firefox the top-parent div expands.

html

```
    <div class="post_bg">
        <div class="post_inner">
            <div class="blue">date</div>
            text
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.post_bg {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  outline: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.post_inner {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.blue {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #55a4cc;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: 40px;
}
```

Here is a picture showing my problem:

[image]

And while I'm at it, how to I get my "text" to the top of the box?

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Comment: @thirtydot http://jsfiddle.net/g4m5v/1/

Comment: just use `border` instead of `outline` - http://jsfiddle.net/g4m5v/4/

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: That's going to mess up the design.

Comment: @My Head Hurts: Comparing the two fiddles, you'll notice the top gray border is gone in the modified one. That's filled in by the `outline`. The `border-top` is actually the white "highlight-like" region beneath the top `outline`.

Comment: @Boltclock Ah, yeah I see. They are really different - prob should have tried it before asking

Comment: The main problem here is that there's nothing that specifies how outlines should be drawn with respect to positioned descendants... so it's hard to tell which browsers are doing it right, which are buggy, and stuff.

Comment: But I want it to look like it does in IE and Chrome... but firefox wont work with me. Seems like it is the outline that breaks it for firefox, guess I will have to do without. How do I get the text starting from the top, not like now under the blue box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the outline to work in Firefox replace:

```css
outline: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
```

With:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d8d8d8;
```

To get the text aligned to the top make `.post_inner` `position: relative;` and `.blue` `position: absolute;`. Then adjust `.blue`'s position accordingly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/8SyGV/

CSS:

```
.post_bg {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    left: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d8d8d8;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
.post_inner {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    position: relative;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #55a4cc;
    height: 40px;
    left: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="post_bg">
    <div class="post_inner">
        <div class="blue">date</div>
        text
        <br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using firefox 3.6 and that doesn't work for me. You lose the `outline` all together (there is no outer border)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts 3.6? Yeah, that's pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "bug" in Firefox 3.X as described [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/03/css-bugs-and-inconsistencies-in-firefox-3-x/).

There is a workaround which I found [here](http://enotionz.net/2011/07/07/firefox-outline-overflow-fix) that uses `:before` to prepend an absolutely positioned container which applies the `outline` instead.

So for your code you would remove `outline` from `.post_bg` and add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
.post_bg:before {
   bottom: 0px;
   content: '';
   left: 0px;
   margin: 0;
   outline: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   right:  0px;
   top: -1px;      /* -1 to accomodate border-top in .post_bg */
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GqACN/**

You should still use the new implementation of the `.blue` class by @ThinkingStiff to resolve the text issue mentioned in your question.

#### Update

**This bug can be found [here on bugzilla](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418912)**.

However, as pointed out by @BoltClock in the comments above, "*there's nothing that specifies how outlines should be drawn with respect to positioned descendants*" - so to say this is a bug is incorrect since the spec is not clear on how it is to be implemented. Mozilla have just interpreted the specification in a different way to Google and Microsoft.

Comment: Cool, apparently it hasn't been fixed in the last couple of years. It would be great if we could find a link to the ticket in Bugzilla, assuming somebody out there has actually filed one...

Comment: @BoltClock I believe this could be it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418912

Comment: Neither `outline` nor `:before` are supported in IE7 or earlier, so if you want to support outdated browsers, you'd need to come up with something else, too.

Comment: @My Head Hurts: Guess my last comment on the question nailed it.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Yeah, I did notice that. I don't think we could support IE7 without adding an extra div directly to the code. Also, it wasn't my intention to have a go at your answer, it was a clever one, I just felt I should mention that it wouldn't work as you may have thought on Firefox 3.X or IE8 (where it had worked originally on IE8)

Comment: @BoltClock I think it pretty much did.